# Cocoa Touch: How to detect a missing file on the download server

Tags: cocoa-touch, http, networking, nsurlconnection

My iOS app downloads document files from a server using the `NSURLConnection` class. I use it asynchronously.

It can happen that a document is missing from the server (configuration error). I expected `NSURLConnection` to call my delegate error method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

But it doesn't. Instead, it happily downloads the HTML error 404 web page returned by the server. The only workaround I found was to check the `NSURLResponse` `MIMEtype` property and fail myself when it is `text/html`. It works fine, but I don't like it because it precludes me from supporting html documents at a later date.

How can I check whether a requested URL is indeed present on the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response` delegate method you can ask the response for it's error code.

```
if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        if (httpResponse.statusCode == 404) {
                ...
             //etc
```

Answer (score 1):

When you receive the response (in `-connection:didReceiveResponse:`), you get to query the response. Because you're using HTTP, it will be a kind of `NSHTTPURLResponse`, though you may want to test for that. Anyway, it will tell you a `-statusCode`, which might be 200, 404 or something else.